# What is the source of the following narration about pilgrimage during the last hour?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

According to [islam.org.hk](http://www.islam.org.hk/HY/signsofthelastday/the_rejection_of_the_true_religion.html):

> Another among the signs of the End Times is that the pilgrimage will
>   be made for the sake of travel, business, ostentation or begging.
>
> Such a time will come when the rich go on pilgrimage for purposes of
>   travel, the comfortably off for business, the wise for boasting and
>   outward show, and the poor to beg. (Narrated by Anas (r.a.))

Where is this quote from?

Comment: I seen many websites say the same hadith but there are no origins of it that are include apart from that it was narrated by Anas. It is a bit difficult to find the source of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sunni View

The hadith you refer to is mentioned in several books as discussed below (and others). The grading of the hadith is either very weak or fabricated.

---

**It'haf Al-Jama'a**

From It'haf Al-Jama'a (إتحاف الجماعة بما جاء في الفتن والملاحم وأشراط الساعة), Vol. 2, p. 22, quoted from a long hadith attributed to Ibn 'Abbas through the Prophet (ﷺ), referenced in Al-Jalees Al-Salih (see below):

> عند ذلك يا سلمان يحج الناس إلى هذا البيت الحرام؛ تحج ملوكهم لهوًا
> وتنزهًا، وأغنياؤهم للتجارة، ومساكينهم للمسألة، وقراؤهم رياء وسمعة
>
> At the time, O Salman, people will do hajj to the Great Mosque
> [Mecca]: their kings for fun and picnic, their rich for trade, their
> needy for begging, and their readers for showing off and reputation.
>
> ```
> — NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care.
> ```

In the same book, Ibn Mardawaih ([ابن مردويه](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88_%D8%A8%D9%83%D8%B1_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%8A%D9%87)) said that the hadith is weak, and its content is partially correct in meaning.

The chain of narration is:

1. The Prophet (ﷺ)
2. 'Abdullah ibn 'Abbas
3. Ibrahim ibn Makhlad
4. 'Abdel-Malik ibn 'Eid
5. Sulaim ibn Muslim
6. Ibrahim ibn Makhlad
7. Mohammad ibn Abi Sho'aib
8. Mohammad ibn Al-Hussain
9. Al-Mu'afa ibn Zakaria

This grades the hadith as very weak (da'eef jiddan) due to Sulaim ibn Muslim Al-Khashab, who used to fabricate hadith.

---

**Ihya' 'Ulum al-Din**

From [Ihya' 'Ulum al-Din](https://archive.org/stream/GAZALIIhyaUlumAlDin1/GAZALI__Ihya-Ulum-Al-Din-1#page/n100/mode/1up) (إحياء علوم الدين) Vol. 1, p.200 (English) or p.262 (Arabic), [Abu Hamid Al-Ghazali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Ghazali) referenced to this hadith without full attribution:

> وقد روي في خبر من طريق أهل البيت إذا كان آخر الزمان خرج الناس إلى الحج
> أربعة أصناف سلاطينهم للنزهة وأغنياؤهم للتجارة وفقراؤهم للمسألة وقراؤهم
> للسمعة
>
> It was narrated that Ahl Al-Bayt informed: In the latter days, the
> people will go to Hajj will be of four types: The sultans [rulers] for
> picnicking, the rich for trade, the poor for begging, and the readers
> for fame.
>
> ```
> NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care.
> ```

[Al-'Iraqi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zain_al-Din_al-%27Iraqi) in Takhreej Ahadeeth Ihya' 'Ulum al-Din ([تخريج أحاديث إحياء علوم الدين](https://archive.org/stream/waq15902/15902#page/n669/mode/1up)) Vol. 2, p. 670 is quoted:

> وقال العراقي: رواه الخطيب من حديث أنس بإسناد مجهول وليس فيه ذكر
> السلاطين ورواه أبو عثمان الصابوني في كتاب المائتين فقال تحج أغنياء
> أمتي للنزهة وأوساطهم للتجارة وفقراؤهم للمسألة وقراؤهم للرياء والسمعة
>
> And Al-Iraqi said: This was narrated by Al-Khateeb from the hadith of
> Anas with an unknown chain of narration, and does not mention the
> sultans. It was also narrated by Abu 'Uthman Al-Sabooni in his book
> Al-Ma'atain as: The rich of my umma will do hajj for picnicking, and
> their mid-class for trade, and their poor for begging, and their
> readers for fame and showing off.
>
> ```
> NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care.
> ```

The conclusion from this source is that it is a hadith with an unattributed chain of narration, i.e., fabricated.

---

**Al-Jalees Al-Salih Al-Kafi**

In Al-Jalees Al-Salih Al-Kafi ([الجليس الصالح الكافي والأنيس الناصح الشافي](https://shamela.ws/book/7301/442)), Al-Twaigri wrote in Ch. 61, p. 446 that Abu Al-Faraj Al-Mu'afa ibn Zakariya narrated this long hadith through a chain of narration that ends with ibn 'Abbas (same chain as the one in It'haf Al-Jama'a above):

> قال: إي والذي نفسي بيده، عندها
> يحج أمراء الناس لهوا وتنزها، وأوساط الناس للتجارة، وفقراء الناس
> للمسألة، وقراء الناس للرياء والسمعة
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Yes, by whom my soul is in His hand, at that
> time, the princes will do hajj for fun and picnic, and the mid-class
> for trade, and the poor for begging, and the readers for showing off
> and reputation.
>
> ```
> — NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care.
> ```

This has the same chain of narration as It'haf Al-Jama'a, and is accordingly equally graded as very weak.